# Initialize dataTable from separate .php table

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, html-table

I am trying to initialize a dataTable from a separate .php file that builds a table.  It builds the table okay, but the dataTable properties do not seem to be in effect.

Here is my code:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#live_table').load("table.php");
                var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                    $('#live_table').load("table.php");
                }, 2000);
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
                $('#data').dataTable();
            });
        </script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="live_table">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

table.php

```
<table id="data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Foo</th>
            <th>Bar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

index.php is meant to refresh the table every 2000ms and table.php is actually more complex in my real situation and requires conditional cell backgrounds and links which is why I didn't choose to use the server side processing (JSON) for table data.

Any idea why the `$('#data').dataTable();` command isn't working?

Comment: Even though it is complex as you say, I'm still positive that it would be faster and easier to use Server Side. However, to answer your question, we need some more details. Such as what properties are not taking effect. Is it not working at all, you see the style but no table/functions?

Comment: All I see is the table in normal HTML format, it does not look like a "dataTable" table.

Comment: I have reproduced the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/sAnUL/

Comment: Also, is it possible to assign individual background colors and links from a Server Side setup?

Comment: @Das.Rot If you use servside you can do the exact same things as in any other approach. You can style it in any ways you like, use links with separate styles and so on.

Comment: @Iro I will have to look into that, I see now that the way I have it implemented is not good at all as the refresh is far from ideal!

Comment: @Das.Rot If you need help, you know where to find us ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not loading because you are using a selector that does not exist yet.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#live_table').load("table.php");
            var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                $('#live_table').load("table.php");
            }, 2000);
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $('#data').dataTable(); //This line should be in table.php
```

Technically there is no element #data in the DOM. You should put the table initialization in the table.php file.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is the call to `.dataTable()` is occurring before the table is actually loaded, since `.load` call happens asynchronously and the rest of the code keeps running.  You need to call `.dataTable()` after the request has finished by using the third parameter to [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#live_table').load(
    "table.php",
    {},
    function() { $('#data').dataTable(); }
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sAnUL/1/

Comment: I am not sure why, but this didn't work for me.  I just placed the `$('#data').dataTable();` in my table.php and it worked fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use callback function of `load()` method:

```
$('#live_table').load("table.php", function(){
    $('#data').dataTable();
});
```

or use `ajaxSuccess()`:

> Attach a function to be executed whenever an Ajax request completes successfully. This is an Ajax Event.

```
$('#data').ajaxSuccess(function(){
    $(this).dataTable()
})
```